# how do I reverseproxy the hostname of a subdomain to a different domainname?

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy, subdomain, virtualhost

I want to reverseproxy a subdomain to another domainname with the same hostname.

Example:

fitzefatze.sourcedomain.com should get the content of:

fitzefatze.targetdomain.com

This should be dynamic, so that every hostname will be translated to the target domain name.

I guess this could be done with the ProxyPass directive but I don't know how to get the host name for the target:

something like this

    ServerName *.sourcedomain.com

```
ProxyRequests Off
<Proxy *>
    AddDefaultCharset off
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all #
</Proxy>

ProxyPass / $1.targetserver.com
```

Answer (score 2):

There's the ProxyPassMatch directive, but it does specify the following restriction:

> The URL argument must be parsable as a URL before regexp substitutions (as well as after). This limits the matches you can use. For instance, if we had used
>
> ProxyPassMatch ^(/.*.gif)$ http://backend.example.com:8000$1
>
> in our previous example, it would fail with a syntax error at server startup. This is a bug (PR 46665 in the ASF bugzilla), and the workaround is to reformulate the match:
>
> ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*.gif)$ http://backend.example.com:8000/$1

I don't know if it will accept http://$1.targetserver.com as a valid URL before substitution -- try it out and let us know!

As mentioned by Shane, you could also use mod_rewrite, but you should be aware that the proxying done by mod_rewrite does not use connection pooling -- each new request will create a new proxy connection on the fly. Therefore you will not be able to benefit from the persistent connection pooling done by ProxyPass, nor will you able to fine-tune its behaviour with the per-connection-pool options that ProxyPass provides (keepalive, timeout, connectiontimeout, retry, min/max, etc.).

Note that there doesn't appear to be a matching ProxyPassReverseMatch directive for either alternative.

Comment: Excellent first post. Keep up the good work!

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you'll need to use `mod_rewrite`..

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.sourcedomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://%1.targetdomain.com/$1 [P,L]
```

..and keep in mind, `ProxyPassReverse` won't work here so any `30x` response will not be translated.